# The rule doesn't apply to words with than two syllables

Tags: prepositions

> The rule doesn't apply to words with two syllables.

> The rule doesn't apply to words with *than* two syllables.

Does the second sentence work? If it does, does it mean "with more than" or "with less than", or either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the second sentence does not work. The preposition / conjunction "than" generally must follow a comparative adjective or adverb.* For example: "**more** than", "**smarter** than", "**more quickly** than". Also, the preposition "with" requires an object, and the phrase "than two syllables" can not function as an object.

*There are a few other situations in which "than" may be used, e.g., following the word "other". However, you seem to be looking for a comparative form.